# Using deny from all inside htaccess in a subdomain restrict access to itself

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess

I am facing a strange situation where i couldn't find a proper answer to.

I am using some kind of an API where i can send responses to certain requests from the same root domain.

My api is in a subdomain (https://api.mysite.com)
And there are some client frameworks in `PHP`, such as

- mysite.com
- mobile.mysite.com
- admin.mysite.com

I only want this API be accessible from the same root domain. Therefore i added AccessControlAllowOrigin headers which are working quite good.

But the problem is, i also want to make sure that nobody can access to this API, because CORS is browser based, and i can easily access this API from other tools such as POSTMAN.

That is why i added some code to my `.htaccess` so that only from the same **IP** can access my system.

Here is my .htaccess file.

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 9999


SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(mysite.com|mobile.mysite.com|admin.mysite.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
Header merge Vary Origin

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

order allow,deny
deny from all
allow from // MY IP HERE

<RequireAny>
Require ip allow from // MY IP HERE
</RequireAny>

RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]


# DirectoryIndex none.none
# Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But the problem is the system blocks itself, i mean when i try to access my API with an `AJAX Request`, i get en error like this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
```

What am i missing.

Thanks.

> PS `Require ip allow from // MY IP HERE` flag is not blocking anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to allow only connections from local IP (your server's IP):

```
Require local
```

And to authorize external IPs:

```
Require ip your_authorized_ip
```

These are the new Apache2.4 notations.
See [the Apache2.4 Access Control docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/howto/access.html) for more detailed info/configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried in case, but require directive is not blocking requests from other clients. I am trying my ajax requests on a program called POSTMAN where i can see the response. It is showing the response while it shouldn't.

Comment: Are you allowing your `.htaccess` files to override your `apache2.conf`? ie: `<Directory /var/www/path/to/api/subdomain>AllowOverride All
</Directory>`

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `<Directory /home/mysite/api>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
order allow,deny
deny from all
allow from IP` in htaccess

Comment: Yep, try to delete all inside `<Directory></Directory>` and replace with `Require all denied`. You shouldn't be able to access it anymore, and that would prove that something is wrong in your configuration or htaccess file

Comment: By using only `<Directory>Require all denied</Directory>` I couldn't access to anythig inside my subdomain. What does this tell you?

Comment: That's it, if you use `<Directory>Require all denied</Directory>`, you couldn't access anything on that subdomain. So, you just have to set `<Directory>Require local</Directory>` to authorize only local connections to access your api subdomain. Try both versions (in your `apache.conf` file) and tell me what's happening

Comment: `Require local` or `Require MyIP` does not block connections from outside. `Require all denied` blocks everything including local. Using both   also blocks everything. My mind's all messed up. Thanks again by the way.

Comment: Have you tried `Require all denied` first and on the next line `Require local`? Are you doing this on your apache.conf file and not on your htaccess file?

Comment: Yes i am doing this on htaccess file. And yes i tried `Require all denied` first and on the next line `Require local` And vice versa

Comment: Ok, maybe I misexplained, I wanted you to do it on your apache.conf file, but **NOT** in your htaccess file :)

Comment: At the moment, i do not have enough resources to edit httpd.conf. But i don't think that is the case. Because when i add my laptop's IP address to htaccess, iti is working well. But i do not want to access the API directly, i just want my client frameworks access it and gets the response. I think i am missing something else here.

Comment: And if, instead of `Require local` you do `Require ip your_server_ip`?

Comment: :( I've tried every possible combination. With `require`, `order allow deny`, inside `<document> tags`. Nope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185617/discussion-between-amaury-and-ruzgar).

Answer (score 0):

In case any body facing the same issue, thanks to @Panama Jack for the answer in SO, here is how i did.

```
SetEnvIf Referer "example\.com" canpass
SetEnvIf Referer "^mobile\.example\.com" canpass2

Require env canpass
Require env canpass2
```

Here is the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257328/htaccess-require-host-domain-not-working-correctly).